# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in line

Tags: php, parse-error

When I trying to run a file using cron jobs I am getting the following

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/joshand2/public_html/application/models/model_posting.php on line 1787`

The line in 1787 is `goto endofloop;` I don't know if there is any syntax related issue in this line or not but the `endofloop` refers to.

**endofloop:**

```
if (file_exists("cookies/".$this->job_id."_job_".$this->site_id."_site.txt")) {
    echo "The file cookies/".$this->job_id."_job_".$this->site_id."_site.txt exists"; 
    unlink("cookies/".$this->job_id."_job_".$this->site_id."_site.txt");
}
```

Can anybody help me in fixing this error?

Comment: post some more code, error is not there in the code provided

Comment: Probably you are using a PHP version that does not support `goto` (< 5.3). But you 99.999999% certainly should not use `goto` anyway. http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/goto.png

Comment: Courtesy of php.net: http://php.net/manual/en/images/0baa1b9fae6aec55bbb73037f3016001-xkcd-goto.png

Comment: @DaveRandom - Is there any alternate keyword instead of goto?

Comment: I just started talking about random text within the code and then DaveRandom jogged my memory about the new feature `goto`.  Check your PHP version by using `phpinfo()`

Comment: @phpisuber01 - Haha... Superb!! but do I have an alternative for `goto` ??

Comment: @lock Functions. or Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: @lock `endofloop` suggests breaking out of a loop; you can also use `break` for this.

Comment: We need to see a bit more of your code to come up with a better way to write it...

Comment: `goto` in php ??? what is the idea? years ago we run like hell far of `goto`...

Comment: `goto` is a function of PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely need to re-factor your code to avoid using `goto` jump labels.

Because:

1. It sounds as if your PHP version may not support it yet (Version <5.3 as suggested by DaveRandom)
2. There is probably a way to avoid the jump labels and still achieve the same behavour

Answer (score 1):

Don't use goto.  At the very least define a function instead.  An example for your code would be:

```
function endOfLoop($job_id, $site_id) {
    $file = 'cookies/' . $job_id . '_job_' . $site_id . '_site.txt';
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        echo 'The file ' . $file . ' exists'; 
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

And then where you are using goto, just call your function instead:

```
endOfLoop($this->job_id, $this->site_id);
```

The fact that you are labelling something 'endofloop' definitely suggests you need to rethink your code.